# Add icon to ProgressBar in Android

Tags: android, animation, progress-bar

I am new to the Android animation, and I would like to implement a ProgressBar with an icon that its size increases and decreases through out the animation as shown in the pictures.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[image: SeekBar with Coin]

Use SeekBar instead of ProgressBar.
Thumb property in seekbar put your icon image after progress.

SeekBar XML property--  android:thumb="drawable"

```
 <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seek_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:max="100"
            android:thumb="@drawable/ic_pp" />
```

Comment: a brilliant ways